# Is there a way to access execution context inside of dynamically created processor (POJO processor) in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I've created a Spring Batch based processing framework which allows me to define jobs based on json definition. I'm working with lots of different data processing tasks so I find it useful to configure them via JSON rather than writing tens of Java jobs. Basically it works as follows:

1. I feed my app with configuration JSON looking somewhat like this:

```
{
  "job_name": "some_job",
  "steps": [
    {
      "step_name": "step_1",
      "step_type": "CHUNK",
      "reader": {
        "reader_type": "CSV",
        "path": "/tmp/some.csv",
        "delimiter":";",
        ...
      },
      "processors": [
        {
          "processor_type": "ADD_SUFFIX",
          "source_column": "width",
          "target_column": "width_unit",
          "suffix": "cm"
        }
      ],
      "writer": {
        "writer_type": "CSV",
        "path": "/tmp/result.csv",
        "delimiter": ";"     
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Such definition would basically read some CSV file and append `width_unit` column based on `width` column from the original file.

2. The JSON -> Job transformation process is based on using Jackson's ObjectMapper magic so for eg. processor would be mapped to such simple ProcessorDefinition object:

```java
class SuffixProcessor extends ProcessorDefinition implements ItemProcessor<Row> {
    private String sourceColumn, targetColumn,suffix;
    
    @Override
    public Row process(Row row) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
}
```

As you can see there are no Spring context related stuff. Just a simple object. The same goes for steps, readers, writers, etc. The overall structure of helper objects is more or less like this:

```
JobDefinition job
steps:
      --StepDefinition step_1:
        --ReaderDefinition reader
        --processors:
          --ProcessorDefinition processor_1
          --ProcessorDefinition processor_2
          --ProcessorDefinition ...
        --WriterDefinition writer
      --StepDefinition step_2
        --ReaderDefinition ...
```

3. Then I'm using Configuration class to turn these simple objects into Spring Batch Job:

```java
@Configuration
public class JobConfiguration {


    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    protected StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job getStepDefinitions() throws IOException {

        SimpleJobBuilder simpleJobBuilder = jobBuilderFactory
                .get(getJobDefinition().getName())
                .listener(jobListener)
                .start(getJobDefinition().getStepDefinitions().get(0));

        for (int i = 1; i < getJobDefinition().getStepDefinitions().size(); i++) {
            simpleJobBuilder.next(getJobDefinition().getStepDefinitions().get(i));
        }

        return simpleJobBuilder.build();

    }

    @Bean
    public JobDefinition getJobDefinition() throws IOException {
        // read the json file and map it to the JobDefinition object
        JobDefinition jobDefinition = mapper.readValue(json, JobDefinition.class);
        return jobDefinition;
    }
}
```

So here we land with a job created programmatically. It worked fine till now as I need to store an retrieve some data from the execution context. The question is:

**How could I access job ExecutionContext inside ProcessorDefinition object?** Annotation based solutions does not work.

Have anyone tried anything like this? I've been trying to add SpringContext object to those non bean ProcessorDefinitions as described here: [here](https://confluence.jaytaala.com/display/TKB/Super+simple+approach+to+accessing+Spring+beans+from+non-Spring+managed+classes+and+POJOs) but the ExecutionContext bean is not available while executing `proccess` method of the ProcessorDefinition.

Comment: The problem is that your programmatically created objects aren't beans, which can be problematic if you want to apply Spring AOP or receive callbacks fromt he framework (which is what you want now). So make sure that those things are beans as well, register them in the context (and not only your job, but also the steps, readers, writers, processors, you create).

Comment: `I find it useful to configure them via JSON rather than writing tens of Java jobs`: But in this case you would be writing tens of (untyped) JSON  job definitions instead (with all the issues of checking definitions, creating components via reflection, manually registering components as beans, etc) . Do you agree? Using the XML namespace would be more efficient as Spring will do everything for you + your processor will be declared as a bean in which you can inject the execution context (by making it step scoped and using a SpEL expression for example).

Comment: @M.Deinum I'll try to do that that way and let you know.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I get your point, but it's meant to be webservice friendly in a future. So I quess I have to choose weather I want to map JSON's to beans, or later map JSONS to XML namespace. I'd rather stay with the first one.